# Delete when having 3-way foreign keys relationship?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

In SQL Server and EF I'm having 3 tables A,B,C with foreign keys that refencing as described:

A have foreign key to B.

B have foreign keys to A,C.

C have foreign keys to A,B.

I tried to delete from any of them without success.

Is it even possible to delete from any of them without removing foreign keys?

Comment: maybe look into cascading deletes but I think you'd be better off restructuring your data. It seems like a bad idea to have foreign keys structured like this

Comment: Sounds like you have a design issue here, this is a very unusual design in a database. Please give some realistic names (even if made up) so that we can understand what you are trying to model.

Comment: Are any of the foreign key columns nullable? i..e.: might be a case of begin tran, null required FKs, delete rows, commit tran.

Comment: Not my design and it seem t

Comment: Not my design and I'm not supposed to change it. Unfortunately all of them are not nullable. It's actually pain in the *** even to insert. The solution they found is very simple... don't delete... ever lol